# module "QtQuick" version 2.5 is not installed

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qt-quick

I copied my project from one computer to another both has latest Qt 5.5 installed.

Now I am getting this error:

```
module "QtQuick" version 2.5 is not installed
```

I ran Qt Maintenance tool and updated components (was nothing to update) and made sure 5.5 is installed but it still think QtQuick 2.5 is not installed.

Even when I type "QtQuick 2.", the intellisense predicts 2.5 so its kind of aware of it but how do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, it was project settings issue.

Even though I had qt 5.5 installed, the selected kit for project was using Qt 5.5 where it seems QtQuick 2.5 is not available. Changing that to 5.5.1 fixed it.